# Unwanted data show after add password-comfirm

Tags: forms

In my form I would like to add comfirm password field, the pic below show is before adding comfirm field, there is no data in waiter name field, after adding comfirm-password field there are data in waiter name field and password field, where do they come from. Anyone could please to help me to solve this problem.

```
function waiter_form($form, &$form_state= NULL) {

$form['waiter_name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Waiter Name'),
'#maxlength' => 70, 
'#description' => t("You Need To Add Waiter Name. "),
'#required' => 'true'
);

$form['pass_fields'] = array(
  '#type' => 'password_confirm',
  '#description' => t('Enter the same password in both fields'),
);


$form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Save'),
);

return $form;
}
```

Screen shot of before adding confirm password field

[image]

Screen shot of after adding comfirm password field

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your browser autocomplete functionality is responsible for this.

If it's undesirable something like this should fix it:

```
$form['waiter_name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Waiter Name'),
  '#maxlength' => 70, 
  '#description' => t("You Need To Add Waiter Name. "),
  '#required' => 'true',
  '#attributes' => array('autocomplete' => 'off'),
);
```

I would expect just adding it to the name field is enough, the browser shouldn't try to fill the password if it doesn't perceive a username.